# The button in the template file does the work of the previous button

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views, django-templates

The seller should be able to choose one of the offers by entering the product page and sell the product to him, and then no one else can make an offer on the price of the product.
On the product page, the winner should be notified that you have won.

Now the button comes and there is no error. But the button does the work of the button before it, which is to save.
That is, you click on the button and then the product will be added to the saved list.
And the name of the button is place bid while it should be close product.

views.py:

```
def close_bid(request,  product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Bid_info, pk=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BidForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data["price"] > product.bid_price:
                product.bid_price = form.cleaned_data["price"]
                 product.winner = request.user
                 product.checkclose = True
                 product.save()
                 return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)  
    else:
        form = BidForm()
    return render(request, 'auctions/page_product.html', {'product': product, 'forms': 
                                                                                  
                                                                                 form})
```

page_product.html:

```
{% if product.checkclosed %}
    <p>Congratulations! You have won the auction for this product.</p>
{% else %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ forms }}
        <input type="submit" value="Place Bid">
    </form>
    {% if user.is_authenticated and user == product.seller %}
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'close_bid' product.id %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">Close Product</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

forms.py:

```
class BidForm(forms.Form):
    price = forms.DecimalField(label='Your Bid Price')
```

models.py:

```
class Bid_info(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="seller")
    bid_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    checkclose = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
                                                                blank=True)
```